# data cleaning in hdfs without using hive

Tags: hadoop, sed

Is there an option where i can do hadoop fs -sed , essentially I am trying to replace "\" into "something" in my data directly in hdfs without having to bring data into local and load.

currently I am using getmerge to bring the data into local , clean it and load it with copyFromlocal to hdfs back. it takes a lot of time this way . so is there more easier solution or faster way of doing the replacement of character data.

Comment: Why can't this operation of replace be included in the first mapper of your workflow itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear why you'd use Hive for this anyway.

Pig or Spark are far better options that don't require an explicit schema for the data.

See [Pig `REPLACE` function](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#replace)

In any case, Hadoop CLI has no `sed` option

Another option would be NiFi, but that requires more setup, and is overkill for this task.

Comment: ok, lets say i am loading the data,  dim_site = load 'hdfs://svc/integration/hive/warehouse/erm/iz_erm.db/dr_dim_site/000000_0'... now I want to replace "\" with "#" in the data, how to go about from here. I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: using something like this dim_site = load   'hdfs://integration/hive/warehouse/dd/izdd.db/dim_site/*' USING PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray);
dim_s = limit dim_site 10;
replace_data = FOREACH dim_s GENERATE REPLACE(name,'\','*');

Comment: If you would like to ask a question, please create a new post for it.

Comment: 1) You need a `DUMP` or `STORE` to output anything 2) Your data is in the Hive warehouse, so I would suggest just using Hive or use Pig's HCatalog functions to write to a secondary table